# Two Questions on for Rsync - rsync by date and by file name

Tags: linux, rsync

I have two questions with respect to rsync:

1:  I have a bunch of files which are incremented by day of the year.  Ex:  file.txt.81, file.txt.82, etc.  Now, these files are in different directories:

data1/file.txt.81
data1/file.txt.82
data2/file2.txt.81
data2/file2.txt.82

How can I have rsync get only the *.82 files and not even touch the other files

2:  Now I have a similar data directory structure as above.  How can I rsync all files that have been modified on or after a specific day?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer for #1`rsync -avz --include "**/" --include=*.82 --exclude=* /path/from /path/to`

This will recursively (-a) include the directories and search them for anything matching .82 and exclude everthing else.  You can find more info on this in `man rsync` and look for "exclude patterns"

For #2 I would find some way to do it with find and mtime.  To find files modified in past 60 minutes with the name *.82 this should work:
`sudo find /path/from -mmin 60 -type f -name *.82`

EDITED: too many backticks